# Send a toast notification from a Windows Service : UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, notifications, toast

I try to send a Toast Notification in a Windows Service, but I have this exeption:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Accès refusé. (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
> à Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotifier.Show(ToastNotification notification)

My service run with the local system account. I tried with my personal account but it's the same.

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications;
...
ToastContentBuilder toast = new ToastContentBuilder()
                    .AddText("My title", hintMaxLines: 1)
                    .AddText("My text");
toast.Show();
```

Windows 10, .Net 4.8, C#